# how to change the directory using SshSession.executeCommand(<command>) maverick api, in java for windows

Tags: java, apache, cd

I have used SshSession.executeCommand() maverick apache api to make the directory.
But my expected creation of directory location is different (but it's getting created in my application start area, bin).
So, I'd like to change the directory to my expected location (Root directory of remote machine).
But I tried like:

```
SshSession session = null;
session = ssh.openSessionChannel();
session.requestPseudoTerminal("vt320", 80, 24, 0, 0);
session.executeCommand(cd /); // "/" is root dir
session.executeCommand(mkdir folder/folder1/...);
```

Even after that, getting the currect dir as "bin" only.

Could anyone please help me in this?